# Radio button check on load from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi guys i have a table/form I'm making and in one of the `<TD>`.

I'm making a button to ban or unban a user but i would like it to auto check based on whats already in the DB using MySql.

Here is what i currently have but its not auto populating:

```
echo "<td>" . '<form method="post" action=""> <input type="hidden" name="id" value=' . $ID . '>  Ban:<input type="radio" value="1" name="unban" onclick="javascript: submit()" if({$row[\'Banned\']}==1 {echo "checked"; }/><br> Unban:<input type="radio" value="0" name="name" onclick="javascript: submit()" if({$row[\'Banned\']}=="0 {echo "checked"; }/><br /> </td>';
```

Thanks in advanced.

EDIT: Here is the complete code minus the DB info:

```
$LINK = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with username and password.
mysql_select_db($DB_DTBS) or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

$search = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users') or die(mysql_error()); 

$match  = mysql_num_rows($search);


if($match > 0){
    echo "Users";
    echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Access Level</th>
            <th>Ban</th>
            <th>Ban Reason</th>

            </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    $ID = $row['AccountID'];
   # echo "<td>" . $row['AccountID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<form method="post" action=""><select     onchange="this.form.submit()" name="access"><option value="0">Standard</option><option    value="300">VIP</option><option value="500">Moderator</option><option value="600">Admin</option><option value="700">OP</option></select></td>';
    #echo "<td>" . $row['Banned'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . 
    '<form method="post" action=""> <input type="hidden" name="id" value=' . $ID . '>
    Ban:<input type="radio" value="1" name="unban" onclick="javascript: submit()" '.    (($row['Banned'] == "1") ? 'checked=checked"' : '').' /><br> 
       Unban:<input type="radio" value="0" name="name" onclick="javascript: submit()" '.   (($row['Banned'] == "0") ? 'checked=checked"' : '').' /><br /> </form></td>';
     #the above now pulls code thanks to Fred and everyone els
    #echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="reason" value=""> </form> </td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row['Banned_Reason'] . "</td>";
    #echo "<td>" . $row['LastLogin'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";



} else {
    echo("Oops Something Went wrong");
}


?>
```

*note the above is already in php tags.

Comment: why if your form inside the `<td>` element?

Comment: Tagged as `mysql` with no SQL, *lovely*. Which API are you using?

Comment: Cause its clearly already pulling the mysql hence the $row varible

Comment: @ghost its inside the TD because the I'm making a Table it will show username email and give me the option to ban or unbar.

Comment: You're missing `)` brackets for both your conditionals and a misplaced quote. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which would have signaled it.

Comment: @Ryan I noticed you added a mention of me in your question/code. It's best that you change your code back to the way it was and simply put in an answer yourself with the mentions in text instead of embedded comments in the code. Stack lets you do that and you can mark it as accepted when it lets you. When future users visit the question, they will see nothing wrong with it and stand at downvoting the answers given because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest rewriting this approach, but if you want some logic inside that echo, you cannot include them inside the string and expect them to be interpolated as logic since they will be considered as strings. You can utilize a ternary in this case:

```
echo '
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value=' . $ID . ' />
            Ban: <input type="radio" value="1" name="unban" onclick="javascript: submit()" ' . (($row['Banned'] == 1) ? 'checked=checked' : '') . ' /> <br/> 
            Unban: <input type="radio" value="0" name="name" onclick="javascript: submit()" ' . (($row['Banned'] == 0) ? 'checked=checked' : '') . ' /> <br/>
        </form>
    </td>
';
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ghost I'm very new to php so this is all a great learning experience have a great night. Also the same logic would go for the drop down?

Comment: @Ryan if your intention is write each option with that selected ternary, its going to be too long to write each one, unless your up to it. yes you can

Comment: @Ryan As per [**your edit fix**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26199247/revisions), you seem to have used Ghost's code to fix your code. You should accept his answer since it looks identical to his. I will upvote this answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that was odd, maybe a browser issue i guess. new browsers seem to just recognize `checked` alone.

Comment: @Ryan It was a pleasure, you're welcome. Glad to have helped, *cheers*.

Comment: @Ghost Old browsers such as IE7 accept `checked` and `checked=checked`, but only accept `disabled` and not `disabled=disabled`, strangely enough. A quick "FYI" ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- strange indeed.

Comment: @Ghost IE's just weird that way. Well, I'm off to lah-lah land. Take care, *cheers* ;)

Comment: @Ghost I found the Q&A after doing a Google search (today) when I was trying to use a ternary for a radio button coming from DB and was having a hard time with something I was trying to use. I noticed the extra double quote inside all `'checked=checked"'` which should (most likely) not be there, since it's actually one too many and that alone will cause a parse error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wow an oldies post :D haven't stumbled most posts this old, made the correction including the missing `</form>` tag

Comment: @Ghost Yes, a few years old but the question did come up ranked rather high in a Google search. I think it's one of the better uses of a ternary inside an echo that I've seen and TBH, have been doing something differently for a few scripts I had written about a year ago where I had a hard time having radio buttons be checked if a row equaled "something". This one (the Q&A) is a real time saver. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

**Edit for future readers**.

OP found the solution. Hopefully OP will post it as an answer.

> i fixed it i just had to add 'checked=checked"' : ''). –  Ryan

---

Originally posted answer for [**originally posted question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26199247/1) before OP's edited question with modification to show it as being working code.

You're missing closing `)` brackets for both your conditionals along with an extra quote in the other.

```
if({$row[\'Banned\']}==1
                        ^ bracket missing
```

which should read as

```
if({$row[\'Banned\']}==1)
```

and

```
if({$row[\'Banned\']}=="0
                       ^ ^ extra quote and bracket missing
```

which should read as

```
if({$row[\'Banned\']}==0)
```

---

**Edit:**

You have two `<form>` tags but only one closing `</form>` tag. You need to close them both off.

Plus this line is commented out:

```
#echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="reason" value=""> </form> </td>';
```

If that is part of your working code, you need to have an echo'd `</form>` tag and for both forms.

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which would have signaled it.

Comment: Ok thank both of you i have checked both ways you have sent me and its still not marking them checked.
the only error I'm getting is I'm using a depreciated mysql_connect but i know that.

Comment: @Ryan You're welcome. If you're getting a deprecated error because of `mysql` then it shouldn't be fetching from DB. Does `mysql_` functions still work on your server and it's just this script that's not working?

Comment: @Ryan I noticed something else. You have two `<form>` tags but only one closing `</form>`. That could be it. You need to close both `<form>` tags. The one you have now is commented out.

Comment: Ill try mysql_ but yes at this moment everything works it pulls data down just right its just not wanting to pre select the radio buttons. and i did try adding the </form> and so far nothing has worked

Comment: @Ryan Give me some time, I'll see if I can setup a DB on my end. Can't promise anything, but I'll get back to you either way.

Comment: @Ryan That's great. I've set one up and was still scratching my head about why it wasn't working lol - oh well, another happy ending story then.